# Using SQLAlchemy with per-entity file hierarchy - can't test

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest

I looked over StackOverflow and were able to find snippets, but not a proper solution to the following problem. I have a model hierarchy in which a job has files (file_models), and files (file_models) have file_events forming the history of a given file.

My project hierarchy's relevant part is this:

```
[project root]
  \ aoget
     \ model
       \ __init__.py
       \ file_event.py
       \ file_model.py
       \ job.py

  \tests
    \ test_flie_event.py
    \ test_file_model.py
    \ ...
   
  pytest.ini
```

The listed `__init__.py` file contains this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, DeclarativeBase

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker())


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

from .file_model import FileModel
from .job import Job
from .file_event import FileEvent
```

I know this is ugly, but this at least made it work as long as there were no explicit imports in both classes (in case of file_model and file_event I could shape the file in a way in which the import FileModel is not there in FileEvent).

My models inherit from this `__init__.Base`. Interestingly the application starts and seems to work (don't do any actual persistence yet), but when I want to run a trivial test - construct a FileEvent object -, I get this:

`sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'Mapper[FileModel(file_model)]'. Original exception was: When initializing mapper Mapper[FileModel(file_model)], expression 'Job' failed to locate a name ('Job'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'aoget.model.file_model.FileModel'> class after both dependent classes have been defined`

Note that FileModel imports Job and Job imports FileModel.

My test.ini:

```
[pytest]
pythonpath = aoget
testpaths = tests

[coverage.report]
skip_empty = true
```

I undertand that the problem is two files mutually referencing each other, but that is expected, as they are relational objects.

How can I organize the models or do something about my test settings to be able to use the models in tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I do something like this.  Putting together this example seems kind of crazy now after finishing it but it works as your project gets larger, I have `run.py` just as an example.  For larger larger projects I would avoid putting logic into the model classes all together because it really starts to break down.  Then you can have all the data model classes in a single file and completely avoid this problem.

#### directory layout

```
src/tproj/model/
src/tproj/model/__init__.py
src/tproj/model/meta.py
src/tproj/model/classes.py
...
src/tproj/model/user.py
src/tproj/model/profile.py
...
src/tproj/run.py
tests/conftest.py
tests/test_profile.py
...
```

#### src/model/meta.py

You could store a sessionmaker here as well.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


def get_engine(environ, echo=False):
    return create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{environ['DB_USERNAME']}:{environ['DB_PASSWORD']}@/{environ['DB_NAME']}", echo=echo)
```

#### src/model/classes.py

This is kind of crude but is an easy way to avoid circular imports as long as you do not reference classes in the model scope, see `user.py` for an example.

```py
from .user import User
from .profile import Profile
```

#### src/model/user.py

Here we use sqlalchemy's system to resolve `'Profile'` but we use our `classes` module to access the actual class in the method scope, `create_profile`, after all the imports are resolved.

```py
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from .meta import Base
from . import classes


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    profile = relationship('Profile', back_populates='user', uselist=False)

    def create_profile(self, db):
        if not self.profile:
            profile = classes.Profile(user=self)
            db.add(profile)
        return profile
```

#### src/model/profile.py

```py
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.sql import func, select

from .meta import Base
from . import classes


class Profile(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'profiles'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    user = relationship('User', back_populates='profile', uselist=False)

    @staticmethod
    def get_profile_counts(db):
        users_without_profile = db.scalar(
            select(
                func.count(classes.User.id)
            ).outerjoin(
                classes.User.profile
            ).where(Profile.id == None))
        users_with_profile = db.scalar(
            select(
                func.count(classes.User.id)
            ).join(
                classes.User.profile))
        return dict(
            users_without=users_without_profile,
            users_with=users_with_profile)
```

#### src/run.py

```py
import os
from pprint import pprint

from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, func

from .model.meta import get_engine
from .model import classes
from .model.meta import get_engine, Base

def main():
    engine = get_engine(os.environ)

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    with Session(engine) as session:
        user1 = classes.User()
        session.add(user1)
        user2 = classes.User()
        session.add(user2)
        profile = user2.create_profile(session)
        session.commit()
        pprint (classes.Profile.get_profile_counts(session))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### tests/conftest.py

```py
import os

import pytest
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session


@pytest.fixture
def engine():
    from tproj.model.meta import get_engine
    engine = get_engine(os.environ)
    yield engine


@pytest.fixture
def session(engine):
    # Force our classes to be loaded.
    import tproj.model.classes
    from tproj.model.meta import Base
    # HACK
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        Base.metadata.create_all(conn, checkfirst=True)
        conn.commit()

    # This requires that you don't actually commit in the code under test.
    with Session(engine) as session:
        yield session
        session.rollback()


@pytest.fixture
def classes(engine):
    from tproj.model import classes as classes_
    return classes_
```

#### tests/test_profile.py

```py
import pytest

def test_user(session, classes):
    user = classes.User()
    session.add(user)
    profile = user.create_profile(session)
    session.flush()
    counts = profile.get_profile_counts(session)
    assert counts['users_with'] == 1
    assert counts['users_without'] == 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the super detailed answer. For testing I use this: self.engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:') and then I don't consider what gets commited to DB and what not.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this out.

I had to add **every model**_ to ***every test file*** I have as an import.

```
from aoget.model.file_model import FileModel
from aoget.model.file_event import FileEvent
from aoget.model.job import Job
```

This is not very scalable (introducing a new model = editing every single test file that works with DB objects), but at least works.